# sql rows duplication PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table TABLE 1 :

| id | id_fk | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | {"a","x"} |
| 2 | 6 | {"b","x"} |

I want to create a new table TABLE 2 by selecting values from TABLE 1 and adding new rows for
each fk (a,b,c). I also need to add a new column value_2 which contain the second value of the JSON:

| id | id_fk | value | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | a | x |
| 2 | 5 | b | y |
| 3 | 5 | c | y |
| 4 | 6 | b | x |
| 5 | 6 | a | y |
| 6 | 6 | c | y |

Answer (score -1):

Solution in Oracle :

```html
create table table2
    as 
SELECT 
row_number() over(order by t.id_fk) id ,
t2.id_fk,
SUBSTR(t.value,INSTR(t.value, '{"')+2, INSTR(t.value, '","')-3) AS value,
replace( SUBSTR(t.value,INSTR(t.value, '","')+3),'"}','' ) AS value_2
FROM table1 t,table1 t2
```

Comment: Hello, the problem is not really to split the json is how to add also the other values (b and c for the id_fk 5)

Comment: improved answer

Comment: SELECT row_number() over(order by t.id_fk) id ,t2.id_fk, SUBSTR(t.value,INSTR(t.value, '{"')+2, INSTR(t.value, '","')-3) AS value, 
replace( SUBSTR(t.value,INSTR(t.value, '","')+3),'"}','' ) AS value_2 FROM table1 t,table1 t2